# concatenation of matrix with different dimensions

Tags: numpy, loops, python-3.7, numpy-ndarray

I did the concatenation of the matrices as shown below in the output.

But it's not very efficient because my code is specific to these two matrices. Is it possible to make it more efficient so that I don't have to rewrite the matrices in the code all the time, but so that it works automatically?

I automatically mean that I don't have to write the matrices I work with in the code, but it passed automatically

I want to put it in a loop with different variations of the matrices that will go through

```
import numpy as np
arr1=np.array([[11, 21,31], [12, 22,32], [13, 23,32], [14, 24,34]])
arr2=np.array([1,2,3,4])

a = np.zeros((arr1.flatten().shape[0],2)) #init the new array
a[:,[0]] = arr1.T.flatten()[:,None]  #fill the first column with the values
a[:,[1]] = np.tile(arr2,3)[:,None]  # fill the second column with values
```

Results

```
array([[11.,  1.],
       [12.,  2.],
       [13.,  3.],
       [14.,  4.],
       [21.,  1.],
       [22.,  2.],
       [23.,  3.],
       [24.,  4.],
       [31.,  1.],
       [32.,  2.],
       [32.,  3.],
       [34.,  4.]])
```

Comment: what do you mean with so that it works automatically?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
In [246]: arr1
Out[246]: 
array([[11, 21, 31],
       [12, 22, 32],
       [13, 23, 32],
       [14, 24, 34]])
In [247]: arr3=np.repeat(arr2[:,None],3,1)   # a variation on your tile
In [248]: arr3
Out[248]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]])
In [249]: arr1.ravel(order='F')            # the transpose ravel
Out[249]: array([11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24, 31, 32, 32, 34])
In [250]: arr3.ravel(order='F')
Out[250]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

and an alternative to assignment to a predefined array:

```
In [252]: np.stack((Out[249],Out[250]), axis=1)
Out[252]: 
array([[11,  1],
       [12,  2],
       [13,  3],
       [14,  4],
       [21,  1],
       [22,  2],
       [23,  3],
       [24,  4],
       [31,  1],
       [32,  2],
       [32,  3],
       [34,  4]])
```

This isn't necessarily faster, more direct, or general.